# How can I get the load average (and only the load average) on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

On all linux boxes `/proc/loadavg` contains the raw load for 1, 5, and 15 minutes. Nothing extra. On OS X machines this file does not exist.

Is there a file or a terminal command which will give me the 1, 5 and 15 minute load averages under OS X, similar to `/proc/loadavg` on Linux? I know `top` and `w` display the load averages but they have a lot more information too. I want *just* the load averages.

Comment: This answer isn't for the command line, so I'm including it as a comment.  Consider something like iStat menus for monitoring load average and other vitals monitoring (warning: this is a commercial app, and no I don't work for the developer).  It integrates some really nice graphical displays in the menubar for OSX: http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/ .

Comment: Thanks @whaley, but I wanted this for the statusbar of [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), for when I SSH into my mac.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use this sysctl:

```
sysctl -n vm.loadavg
```

Answer (score 18):

Take the commands you know (top, uptime, w, etc.) and use other tools to reduce to just the data you want.

An example for `w`:

```
w | head -n1 | cut -d":" -f4
```

An example for `uptime`:

```
uptime | cut -d":" -f4- | sed s/,//g
```

An example of `loads.d`:

```
sudo loads.d | awk '/./ { printf "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", $7, $8, $9 }'
```